# How to get R to check numbers?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have some numbers:

```
numbers<- c(190371877,190890807,193999742,192348099,194907960,194306872,190571682,195878080)
```

Let's say I have a new number, say, `190371877` and I want R to check whether this number is among `numbers` and print `Yes` or `No`.

I thought of using `ifelse`, but could not manage it

Can anyone explain what should ı do?

Comment: `190371877 %in% numbers`

Comment: or with ifelse numbers <- 
 ifelse(numbers == "190371877", "Yes",         
"No")

Comment: @MLavoie you'd probably want an `any()` around that equality check... bu  then you might as well use `%in%`.